# Solr indexing performance degrades with updatelog and field updates

Tags: performance, solr, updates

Here are benchmark results for indexing 1.8 million documents in Solr 4.3, with various configurations:

- **No updatelog** configured in solrconfig.xml. **No uniqueId** field configured in schema.

Takes about **165 seconds** to index documents.
Documents are processed at a **constant rate** of about 9-10000 / second.

- Only **activated updatelog** in solrconfig.xml.

Indexing time is now **180 seconds**. Documents are processed at a **constant rate** of about 9000 / second.

- Only **activated updatelog** in solrconfig.xml and **added uniqueId field** in schema.xml (and in each of the documents sent for indexing).

Indexing time is now **260 seconds**. Documents are processed at a **decreasing rate** which starts off at about 5000 documents per second at keeps decreasing to about 3000 documents / second at the end of the indexing process

- **Activated updatelog** in solrconfig.xml, **added uniqueId field** in schema.xml (and in each of the documents sent for indexing) and **added a field which is incremented** by 1 in the documents sent for indexation.

Indexing time is now **700 seconds**. Documents are processed at a **decreasing rate** which starts off at about 4000 documents per second at keeps decreasing to about 1000 documents / second at the end of the indexing process

I've read the documentation. Basically the only thing said about performance when using updatelog is to make sure you have a decently often autocommit configured, so that the log doesn't get too huge. This I've done (set it to autocommit at 500000 added documents). Other than that there's nothing much on performance.

My question is then:

I understand that performance is slower when we're making field updates (like in my last benchmark). The document is effectively copied and the new value is added. What I don't understand why the performance degrades over time? Why, when there was no updatelog the performance was constant, but when updates are performed as well, the performance degrades (from 5k to 1k documents / second here) ?

Also, how can performance be improved for this situation (field updates) ?

Comment: did you make any headway on this?

Comment: @TejasKale  Unfortunately no. All I've got now is: disable updatelog if you don't truly need it (for example if you only have one Solr instance, aka you're not using Solr Cloud distribution). Disable unique id field if not needed. As for the last part, regarding the update of documents, this is a horribly slow process. Try to make your model/implementation such that you avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: I was using replication for having 2 redundant instances of solr(Any other way to do it?). And I do a bulk update everyday, I guess I will have to look at ways to do a delta import.
Any pointer on if we can change the frequency of distributed log updates sent by the master? I think currently it sends after every ~115 docs

Comment: For replication, you can tell the slave at what time interval to poll the master. See "pollInterval" here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#Slave On the master side, try setting different values for "replicateAfter". You can also manually trigger replication (and optionally, desactivate automatic replication all together) by calling http://master_host/solr/replication?command=backup this way you can schedule replication operations only at convenient hours (when server is not too loaded from clients, etc.